# How to calculate the Fourier coefficients for the function $f(x) = x^2 - \pi^2/3$

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the function $f \in C_{st}$ given by
$$
f(x) = x^2- \frac{\pi^2}{3}
$$
for
$x \in ]-\pi,\pi[$
Then I have to calculate the Fourier coefficient $c_n$ which I am struggling a little bit with.

I know that 
$$
2\pi c_n = \int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2e^{-inx} - \frac{\pi^2}{3} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} dx
$$
For the case where $n \neq 0$ we have
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{3} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} dx = 0
$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
2 \pi c_n & = \int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2e^{-inx} dx = \frac{1}{-in} \left[x^2e^{-inx} \right]_{-\pi}^\pi - \frac{1}{-in} \int_{-\pi}^\pi 2xe^{-inx}  dx \\
& = \frac{2}{in} \int_{-\pi}^\pi xe^{-inx} dx \\
& = \frac{2}{in} \left( \frac{1}{-in} \left[xe^{-inx} \right]_{-\pi}^\pi - \frac{1}{-in} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} dx  \right) \\
& = \frac{2}{in} \left(-2\pi  + \frac{1}{n^2}  (e^{-in\pi} - e^{in\pi})    \right) \\
& = - \frac{4\pi}{in}
\end{align*}
which does not give the right answer. I can't see where I am doing a mistake. Do you mind helping me? Thanks

Comment: For $n=0$ the integral $$\frac{\pi^2}{3} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} \;dx$$ is...

Comment: I am looking at the case where $n \neq 0$. I already calculated $c_n$ for $n =0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the third line from the last,

$$\frac{2}{in}\left[\frac{1}{-i n}(xe^{-inx})\right]^\pi_{-\pi} = \frac{2}{+n^2}(\pi e^{-i\pi n} + \pi e^{i\pi n}) = \color{blue}{\frac{4\pi}{n^2}\cos(n\pi)} $$ 
and the next one $\left[\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-i n x}dx\right]$obviously becomes zero.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The part with the constant is not hard. For the part with $x^2 e^{-inx}$, do some integration by parts :

\begin{align}
\int x^2 e^{-inx}\mathrm{d}x &= [x^2 \frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}] - \int 2x \frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}\mathrm{d}x \\  
\end{align}

Do it again :
\begin{align}
\int xe^{-inx}\mathrm{d}x &= [x \frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}] - \int \frac{e^{-inx}}{-in} \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

I let you fill the holes with suitable values

Comment: I did do integration by parts twice but I don't see where I am doing wrong ..

Comment: I did the calculus vithouth the value at the borns in my edited answer